# Partially increase width of the curve

Tags: vector, inkscape, svg, bezier-curve

I'm reworking an old raster logo to the vector format. There is a part of the logo where the curve widens in one place and then comes back to normal width.

[image]

How can I make this happen in Inkscape? I've tried some path effects like spiro spline or BSpline but the outcome was a mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple, but rather manual method, is to use Path > Stroke to Path, to expand the stroke to a shape, then simply edit the nodes and curves as required.

[image]

Comment: @dallows: Don’t forget that you can [accept](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that you found most helpful.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Use the path effect Power Stroke. You can edit the width in the Nodes tool after applying it.

Draw a copy of the segment that needs the effect to have good control. Applying it to your closed path easily creates a mess.

You can as well draw the problematic curve with the pen tool as a closed shape:

[image]

Comment: I tried both answers and I found the second one more suitable for me. But this one is worth remembering. Thanks